# Bash: edit file component from variable?

Tags: bash, shell

Basically the complete script is all about searching unused images from the xcode project and copy all such images to a temporary directory. Since the script is taking too much time for overall operation so I'm trying to optimize it by reducing operations.

So images are of two types a) `sample.png` & b) `sample@2x.png`

What I'm trying to do is first I'm ignoring `@2x.png` files in order to reduce number of operations which using this command

```
for i in `find ../Resources/Assets ! -name '*@2x.png'`; do
```

and then by using `sample.png` I'm searching that file is getting used in the project or not (I'm using ack and other conditions which is working fine). In case the final output is no i.e. image is not getting used in the project then I'm trying to copy that file to a temporary location i.e

```
cp "$i" "MyFolder"
```

Now I knew that sample.png is unused so I have to copy sample@2x.png as well. By doing this way I have avoided number of search and ack operation on @2x file.

But now my issue is how to change the file and copy @2x file as well ?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please edit it and say clearly at the beginning what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added detailed information. Please check

Comment: Mmmm... I still don't understand. Can you post the code that is too slow so we can understand please? It is unclear how copying some images to another directory is going to help some process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this,

```
cp "$f" "$(sed 's/.png/@2x.png/g' <<< $f)" MyFolder/
```

(OR)

```
cp "$i" "${i/.png/@2x.png}" MyFolder/
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "cp: fts_open: No such file or directory" :( .. Also I have edited my question and added more info.

Comment: Not sure buddy but I keep getting fts_open error... cp "$i" "MyFolder" is working fine just the new copy command is not working.. Are we missing some punctuation error etc. ?

Comment: This echo command is working fine... now how to copy ? echo "$i" | sed 's/.png/@2x.png/g'

Comment: Ah I got the issue.. instead of f it should be i ;) .... cp "$i" "$(sed 's/.png/@2x.png/g' <<< $i)" MyFolder/

Comment: Thank you so much.. I was struggling badly with this :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you don't mean to "mv" the files instead, to get them out of the way.

Regardless, you might try:

```
filename=sample.png
echo "Filename=$filename"
echo "Extra   =${filename/.png/@2x.png}"
```